# Hover effect(change in text color) is also getting delayed upon adding transition for nav links appearance

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar where links appear one by one and I also have a hover effect, but the hover effect is also getting delayed.

in my HTML and CSS webpage I have a navigation bar where navigation links, upon clicking a button appear one by one with a transition delay of 0.15 seconds to the last link to appear has the most delay and I also have a hover effect on navigation links where they change color but the change in color upon hover is getting delayed as well.

Adding some more lines for no reason just because its mostly code and less lines.

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.2rem 0%;
}

.header::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(80px);
  z-index: -1;
}

.header::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, rgba(255, 255, 255, .4), transparent);
  transition: .5s;
}

.header:hover::after {
  left: 100%;
}

.header {
  padding: 0.1rem 5%;
}

.box {
  min-height: 746px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box h1 {
  font-size: 45px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box a.boxBtn {
  padding: 15px 40px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.icons {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

#check:checked~.icons #menu-icon {
  display: none;
}

.icons #close-icon {
  display: none;
}

#check:checked~.icons #close-icon {
  display: block;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(50px);
  box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

#check:checked~.nav {
  height: 17.7rem;
}

.nav a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  margin: 1.5rem 0;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(-50px);
  transition: .3s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

#check:checked~.nav a {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition-delay: calc(0.15s*var(--i));
}
```

```html
<!-- Head -->
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>


<!-- Body -->
<header class="header">
  <a href="#" class="logo">Title</a>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check">
  <label for="check" class="icons">
      <i class="bx bx-menu" id="menu-icon"></i>
      <i class="bx bx-x" id="close-icon"></i>
  </label>
  <nav class="nav">
    <a href="#top" class="active" style="--i:0;">Home</a>
    <a href="meetings.html" style="--i:1;">Meetings</a>
    <a href="#apply" style="--i:2;">Apply Now</a>
    <a href="#Pages" style="--i:3;">Pages</a>
    <a href="#courses" style="--i:4;">Courses</a></li>
    <a href="#contact" style="--i:5;">Contact Us</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Navigation links drop down upon clicking the hamburger menu with a delay of 0.15s but i also have a hover effect that is getting delayed as well.

I was hoping to achieve both the effect without the hover effect getting delayed.
in my html and css webpage i have a navigation bar where navigation links ,upon clicking a button appear one by one with a transition delay of 0.15 seconds to the last link to appear has the most delay and i also have hover effect on navigation links  where they change color but the change in color upon hover is getting delayed as well.

Comment: Note that your HTML markup is invalid. You have a stray `</li>` closing tag while it was never opened and you have no `ul`, `ol`, or `menu` in use.